# Number Range in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing problem number range or price range.

```
product_id  starts_at   price
1815         1          5.95
1815        36          5.62
1815        96          5.00

SELECT *
FROM price_tiers
WHERE product_id = '$productid' AND store_type='W'
ORDER BY `starts_at` ASC
```

I want to show

```
1 to 35 = 5.95
36 to 95 = 5.62
96 to more = 5.00
```

My Code

```
<?php
$price_tiers = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                            FROM price_tiers 
                            WHERE product_id = '$productid' 
                              AND store_type='W' 
                            ORDER BY `starts_at` ASC ")  
                     or die (mysql_error());

while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($price_tiers)) 
{
    echo $starts_at = $myrow['starts_at']. 
                      " to " . "$". 
                      $product_price  =  $myrow['price'].
                      "<br>";
}
?>
```

Your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: what are you currently getting?

Comment: you'll need more complicated code, since you need to deal with TWO rows at the same time. current row for "from" value, and next row for "to" value.

Comment: You might find it easier to unload all the result set into an array of result arrays and then process that array structure. otherwise @MarcB answer is a great start

Answer (score 1):

You'll need something like this:

```
$current = mysql_fetch_assoc($price_tiers);
do {
    $next = mysql_fetch_assoc($price_tiers);
    echo $current['starts_at'];
    echo " to ";
    echo $next['starts_at'] - 1;
    echo $current['price'];
    $current = $next;
while ($next !== false);
```

This won't work perfectly as-is, but should get you started.

Comment: Thank you so much! $price_tiers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM price_tiers WHERE product_id = '1815' AND store_type='W' ORDER BY `starts_at` ASC ")  or die (mysql_error());

 $current = mysql_fetch_assoc($price_tiers);
do {
    $next = mysql_fetch_assoc($price_tiers);
    echo $current['starts_at'];
    echo " to ";
    echo $next['starts_at'] - 1;
    echo " $".$current['price'];
 echo "<br>";
    $current = $next;
}
 while ($next !== false);  Output: 1 to 35 $5.95
36 to 95 $5.62
96 to -1 $5.00 (I want to show 96 to more )

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with user variables, but you have to order twice to get the info you need:

```
  SELECT product_id,
         starts_at,
         ends_at,
         price 
    FROM ( 
      SELECT product_id,
             starts_at,
             @prev_start - 1 ends_at,
             price,
             @prev_start := starts_at 
        FROM price_tier
        JOIN (SELECT @prev_start := NULL) init 
    ORDER BY starts_at DESC
         ) tiers
ORDER BY starts_at ASC
```

You can see it in action on this [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d3bb/1)